# Change the color and opacity of a div rbg

Tags: jquery, html, css, string

I have a textbox and when I type a color and the opacity it saves them into the db,but it doesn't change dynamically only after refresh.
I don't know how to implement my values in this line:

```
$('.box_color_fond_02_transpa').css("background-color:rgb('+$('#col').val()+','+$('#opa').val()+')");
```

col and opa are the ids of the input.

Comment: Add the language tag. jQuery?

Comment: what u mean by **when I type a color and the opacity it saves them into the db,but it doesn't change dynamically only after refresh**

Comment: Show your html also.

Comment: I have this form  <form class="color_div">
                     Color:<input id="col" type="text" size="5">
                     Opacidad:<input id="opa" type="text" size="5">
             </form>                                                                I type the color and the opacity inside the box and it saves them into my data base.
The web page changes color and opacity only if i reload it and it should work without  the need of refresh.

Comment: okay so you mean that color and opacity textboxs define the background color and opacity of page or particular div? is that so?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some correction. Try

```
$('.box_color_fond_02_transpa').css("background-color","rgb("+$('#col').val()+","+$('#opa').val()+")");
```

## [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2765643k/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit sparse on information but it might be as simple as getting the syntax and string concatenation right when calling [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css), which normally expects two parameters:

```
$('.box_color_fond_02_transpa')
    .css('background-color', 'rgba(' + $('#col').val() + ',' + $('#opa').val()+')');
```

Edit: As user3832583 points out, you should also change from rbg to rgba.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the the `rgba` not rgb color as rbg only takes three values from 0-255. The `a` stands for the alpha layer you need for your opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what is the problem.I have do do a function for java for the conversion of the rgb into hex,because im not using 3 values just the color code.